# How to get rid of "c_MAMPRO_unins000_exe"

Tags: windows, mamp

OS: Windows

Program: MAMP

I'm trying to uninstall the current version of MAMP so that I can backdate my version, however I deleted the main folders before realizing there was an uninstaller. I am now left with a file called "C_MAMPRO_unins000_exe" that causes file explorer to become unresponsive if I try to delete it. I'm not sure where it is on my drive, I just have come across it when searching for things containing mamp on my c drive. This was after permanently deleting everything else relating to MAMP and restarting my computer.

The new installer is refusing to uninstall anything on its own, saying it has detected an existing installation. It asks if I'd like to delete this installation, and regardless of if I select yes or no it says "MAMP setup will now exit and the existing MAMP installation will not be removed." I feel as though this remaining file is the issue. This was a fresh install and had not had anything other than simple settings changed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue-

Since I had deleted the main files on accident (and the uninstaller was gone), I had to delete the remaining references in the registry. If you are experiencing the same thing, remove everything relating to "mamp" in the registry and then the new installer should recognize that it's gone- keep in mind I also cleared out temp files and restarted my computer before running the installer again

Hope this helps someone :)